# Hosting ASP.NET Web API alongside a WordPress site on a GoDaddy Windows Hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, plesk

The gist is, my I was requested to make an ASP.NET Web API backend for an app, but the website that the person will be hosting it on already has a wordpress site configured. Is there any way to host that api under `thesite.com/webapi`, for example, with that specific hosting?

The thing is, I'm not familiar with how WordPress is handling its URL routing, I don't have access to the control panel to experiment and without direct access to IIS Management Console I basically have no clue what to do.

Or maybe, if not that, would it be possible to set up a this API on some random port with that hosting? I.e. mysite.com:8001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to create a subdomain for your API like `webapi.thesite.com` because then you won't need to configure your WP site not to catch requests for `thesite.com/webapi` and with this solution you won't need to do anything except registering a new subdomain

Comment: I did that and uploaded the files to the subdomain root folder, but now when I try to access the subdomain it always throws a custom 404 error. Is that still WordPress' influence?